# Flutter Provider on Navigator inject multiple objects

Tags: flutter, routes, provider, visualstatemanager

New to Flutter, I have Provider on top of my app with the class Events. Is there any way to inject more than one object in Navigator builder like MapBox(events.itmaps, events.maps) for example?

```
class Events {
  final String site, fb, itmaps, maps;
  Events({this.site, this.fb, this.itmaps, this.maps});
}
```

```
void main() {
  final events = Events();
  runApp(
    Provider<Events>.value(
      value: events,
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) => MapBox(events.itmaps),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: could you please explain a little bit more? why don't you try Provider.of(context).

Comment: I've tried with your solution but it throws: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'LatLng'. I'm trying to make this dynamic

Comment: in builder: MapBox(events.itmaps) i want to add "maps" from the top declared class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you have some conceptual misunderstandings!. I'll describe two scenarios, hopefully one of them will fit to your requirement.

**Using MultiProvider to inject many Dependencies(Classes/Objects/Stores)**

As https://pub.dev/packages/provider described it would be like this:

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    Provider<Something>(create: (_) => Something()),
    Provider<SomethingElse>(create: (_) => SomethingElse()),
    Provider<AnotherThing>(create: (_) => AnotherThing()),
  ],
  child: someWidget,
)
```

**Passing arguments/props to Widgets**

Despite the descriptions and keywords you used, by looking at your code I can guess you want to pass a second or more input/arguments/props to your screen widget. Every widget input is a class constructor argument. So you need just declare the desire parameters in the constructor of your `MapBox` class.

```
class MapBox extends StatelessWidget {

    EventModel firstInput;
    OtherEventModel secondInput;

    MapBox(this.firstInput, this.secondInput);

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: what i have tryied is the second option of yours but then i got error on "=> MapBox(events.itmaps)" like: 2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found.
Try adding the missing arguments. And you're right, the provider thing i just don't get it

Comment: @blueprint Then you must declare the second input as optional

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how can I do that?

Comment: @blueprint Use square brackets []. More info here: https://zaiste.net/dart-optional-function-parameters/